# Use Python to calculate timing between bus stops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The following is an example of the .csv file of thousands of lines I have for the different bus lines.

**Table:**

| trip_id | arrival_time | departure_time | stop_id | stop_sequence | stop_headsign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107_1_D_1 | 6:40:00 | 6:40:00 | AREI2 | 1 |  |
| 107_1_D_1 | 6:40:32 | 6:40:32 | JD4 | 2 |  |
| 107_1_D_1 | 6:41:27 | 6:41:27 | PNG4 | 3 |  |

**Raw Data:**

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign
107_1_D_1,6:40:00,6:40:00,AREI2,1,
107_1_D_1,6:40:32,6:40:32,JD4,2,
107_1_D_1,6:41:27,6:41:27,PNG4,3,
```

I want to create a table or dataframe that creates a line for each road segment and calculates the time between each arrival_time.

Expected result:

[image]

some other trip_id may share the same RoadSegment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in such cases you can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). Here is an example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('...')
result = pd.DataFrame()

for _, trip_df in df.groupby('trip_id', sort=False):  # type: str, pd.DataFrame
    trip_df = trip_df.sort_values('stop_sequence')
    trip_df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(trip_df['arrival_time'])
    trip_df['departure_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(trip_df['departure_time'])

    trip_df['prev_arrival_time'] = trip_df['arrival_time'].shift()
    trip_df['prev_stop_id'] = trip_df['stop_id'].shift()

    trip_df['RoadSegment'] = trip_df['prev_stop_id'].str.cat(trip_df['stop_id'], sep='-')
    trip_df['planned_duration'] = trip_df['departure_time'] - trip_df['prev_arrival_time']

    trip_df = trip_df.dropna(subset=['planned_duration'])
    trip_df['planned_duration'] = (
        trip_df['planned_duration']
        .apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
        .astype(int)
    )

    result = pd.concat(
        [result, trip_df[['RoadSegment', 'trip_id', 'planned_duration']]],
        sort=False,
        ignore_index=True,
    )


print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see below my solution - this converts the input data into a structured dataclass form, then does the calculation, then puts it back into a csv form.

```py
from attr import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
import csv


@dataclass
class Stop:
    stop_id: str
    trip_id: str
    departure_time: datetime
    arrival_time: datetime

@dataclass
class Segment:
    RoadSegment: str
    trip_id: str
    planned_duration: float

def get_time(s: str) -> datetime:
    """
    Used to convert the object to datetime form
    """
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S')

def get_segment(stop1: Stop, stop2: Stop) -> Segment:
    """
    Calculates the segment between two stops
    """
    assert stop1.trip_id == stop2.trip_id
    return Segment(
        RoadSegment=stop1.stop_id + '-' + stop2.stop_id,
        trip_id=stop1.trip_id,
        planned_duration=(stop2.arrival_time - stop1.departure_time).total_seconds()
    )

# Converts the stops into Stop dataclasses
stops: list[Stop] = []
with open('input.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    first_row = next(r)
    for row in r:
        stops.append(Stop(
            stop_id=row[3],
            trip_id =  row[0],
            arrival_time = get_time(row[1]),
            departure_time = get_time(row[2]),
        ))

# Calculates the segments
segments: list[Segment] = []
previous_stop = stops[0]
for next_stop in stops[1:]:
    segments.append(get_segment(previous_stop, next_stop))
    previous_stop = next_stop

# Outputs to csv
new_csv_list: list[list[str]] = [['RoadSegment', 'trip_id', 'planned_duration']]
for seg in segments:
    new_csv_list.append([seg.RoadSegment, seg.trip_id, str(seg.planned_duration)])

with open('out.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(new_csv_list)
```

Comment: Hello. Could you share an article when should I use `data classes` with `datasets / dataframes` and why? Thank you!

Comment: I get the following error with your code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\BusStopsDeltaTimings\main.py", line 121, in <module>
    segments.append(get_segment(previous_stop, next_stop))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\BusStopsDeltaTimings\main.py", line 96, in get_segment
    assert stop1.trip_id == stop2.trip_id
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError

Comment: Here's an article about reasons for dataclasses: https://towardsdatascience.com/9-reasons-why-you-should-start-using-python-dataclasses-98271adadc66
In general though I would say it's partially personal preference, but it's good to have well structured data formats for large projects, as it allows you to typecheck easily. It means you refer to attributes by their names during calculation instead of by column numbers etc also,

Comment: Re the error - I think this means you have multiple trips in one file. Could you modify the question to contain multiple trips if this is needed and I can modify the answer?

Comment: The answer from @DanilaGanchar works, thank you anyway!

Comment: @Mark I have no subscription. is there any mention of `pandas` in the article?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Apologies I didn't notice the paywall on this. Really this discussion is about allowing the type checker to analyse pieces of information - I actually really like your solution above for readability, but there is a weakness in the way pandas references column names, as it refers to them by string. Essentially the type structure of a pandas table is unknown, so the type checker can't tell if the column you're referring to exists or not. There is another library I was just looking at where they're trying to do this: https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: One way I've used before, such that array operations don't lose speed, is to make a dataclass that contains several arrays. Each item in the dataclass represents a column, then you can refer to each column by name.

Comment: @Mark I know what it is `pandera`, `dataclasses`, `dask`, `pandarallel` etc. And this is not exactly what I wanted to know. I just don't understand why people do this, when I see examples with `dataclasses`+ `pandas`. I just don't see the point at all. That's why I wanted to know a link to an article why to do this and what is the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_result(trip_df):
    # First sort it chronologically using the column of your choice.
    # Assuming stop_sequence column to do this.
    trip_df = trip_df.sort_values(by='stop_sequence')
    #Shift the stop_id column upward (-1) and store it as column called next_stop 
    trip_df['next_stop'] = trip_df['stop_id'].shift(-1)
    #The bottom most value of the 'next_stop' column will be null, while shifting 'stop_id' column upwards last row will
    #not have any info below it, thus null will be assigned and we can just remove it as last stop
    #will be together with the second last stop in second last row.
    trip_df = trip_df[~trip_df['actual_departure_time'].isna()]
    #Concatenating the columns to get the 'Road Segment'
    trip_df['RoadSegment'] = trip_df['stop_id']+'-'+trip_df['next_stop']

    #We do something similar to calculate duration as well. 
    trip_df['actual_departure_time'] = trip_df['departure_time'].shift(-1)
    #Ignore the below conversions if columns are already datetime type.  
    trip_df['actual_departure_time'] = pd.to_datetime(trip_df['actual_departure_time'],format='%H:%M:%S')
    trip_df['arrival_time'] = pd.to_datetime(trip_df['arrival_time'],format='%H:%M:%S')
    trip_df['planned_duration'] = trip_df['actual_departure_time'] - trip_df['arrival_time']

    #Resulting column planned duration will be 'relativedelta' type (which is difference of two datetime types)
    #We can just convert it into seconds by using the total_seconds method of the relativedelta
    trip_df['planned_duration'] = trip_df['planned_duration'].apply(lambda x: int(x.total_seconds()))
    
    return trip_df[['RoadSegment','planned_duration']]




#Assuming the different trip ids are for different buses
# We first group it by trip_id and apply the function on each dfs
# Result will contain a concatenated df with all the trip ids 
    

result_df = data.groupby('trip_id').apply(find_result).reset_index(level=0)
result_df
```